# Xmap - Can't select sitemap on menu item creation. JDate::toFormat fatal error

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, bugs, xmap

I got a call from a client about an issue with xMap component on Joomla 3.3.6. The client wanted to create a menu item for each sitemap, but he was not able to select the desired sitemap from the modal window.

Setting error_reporting on, the modal displays this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JDate::toFormat() in
>   /home/myaccount/public_html/administrator/components/com_xmap/views/sitemaps/tmpl/modal.php
>   on line 110

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JDate::toFormat()` method is deprecated in recent Joomla 3 versions.
Current method is `JDate::format()`.

To fix this, you need to edit the XMap's modal.php template file, that is located in

> /administrator/components/com_xmap/views/sitemaps/tmpl/

Then around line 110 replace the line:

```
$xmlDate = $date->toFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
```

to

```
$xmlDate = $date->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
```

Hopefully the developer will fix this bug with a future release.